# How do I validate a html file with C#?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, validation

I have a C# application that receives an html file. I want to parse and validate it. On output it will return a list of errors or that my html is valid.

Has anyone any idea how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: The validation part of this question makes it quite distinct from questions about simply parsing HTML.

Comment: That's right, I'm not interested in parsing html, I'm interested in validate it for possible errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd run a local instance of the [W3C Markup Validation service](http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html) and communicate with it via the [API](http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html)

Comment: I was not aware there was an API for this, nice find.

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTML Tidy. There is a wrapper for .NET called [TidyManaged](http://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged)

Comment: TidyManaged does not give any functional dll

Comment: Some issues were filed about this, including that the file output doesn't even work (and I confirmed it, despite it apparently being patched already). On the issues page is a link to a version by freethenation that works and requires libtidy32.dll and libtidy64.dll, so I followed gcores's link above and renamed the 32 and 64-bit versions appropriately. Took awhile to figure out, so I thought I'd post that here.

Answer (score 1):

There is an obscure DLL in the framework version 1.0 (!) **Microsoft.mshtml.dll** and that is the only way **in the framework** to deal with DOM. If HTML is XHTML and a valid XML, then you can use XML but otherwise this is the only chance.

Comment: I'd be amazed that that was the *only* way to deal with DOM.

Comment: hmmm, explain me how can you can validate an very elaborate html file with xml. I thought about that too, and I think it's not the best way.

Comment: In what framework? Nobody mentioned a framework. (Oh, and must we resort to name calling?)

Comment: It's not so obscure, it the PIA for Internet Explorer.  Not part of the framework, it's a COM interop library.  Whether IE is a good validator for HTML is, ahem, debatable.