# How to check if string has a correct html syntax

Tags: c#, html, syntax

I would like to check if a given string has a correct html syntax. I don't know which html elements should be inside, the only one thing I know is that string should be a correct html expression.

Anyone has an idea how to check it in C#?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583

Comment: see if the below link can help you
http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: for your own good...please remove the regex tag :)

Comment: I tried exactly with this regex <([a-z]+) *[^/]*?> but it doesn't work properly all the time. It didn't find comments for example, I also thought about putting string into xml structure and than check but I'm not sure if it is the most efficient way...

Comment: @ravenik, HTML is **not a regular language**.  Do not use Regex to parse HTML!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C#, how do I validate a html file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853882/using-c-how-do-i-validate-a-html-file)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use Html Agility Pack : http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

```
string html = "<span>Hello world</sspan>";

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

if (doc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
{
   //Invalid HTML
}
```

Comment: don't forget to add using System.Linq; to use .Count()